# ErrorProvider does not display error message

Tags: c#, winforms, errorprovider

1. In the following code I used `errorProvider.SetError(control, message)` to display the message, but only the `Icon` is shown, the message is not shown, what is wrong?
2. Is there a way to adjust the left margin of the error message only? (I know you can `SetIconPadding`, but I only want left margin to be changed)

   ```
   public static DialogResult ShowDialog()
   {
     var inputBox = new Form { ClientSize = new Size(520, 225), FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog };        
     var panel = new TableLayoutPanel { Size = new Size(460, 100), Location = new System.Drawing.Point(45, 15) };        
     var errorProvider = new ErrorProvider { Icon = SystemIcons.Exclamation, BlinkStyle = ErrorBlinkStyle.NeverBlink };        
     errorProvider.SetIconAlignment(panel, ErrorIconAlignment.BottomLeft);

     var okButton = new Button
     {
       Size = new System.Drawing.Size(70, 30),
       Location = new Point(330, 180),
       Text = "OK"
     };

     okButton.Click += new EventHandler((sender, e) => { errorProvider.SetError(panel, "Test Error"); });
     inputBox.Controls.Add(panel);
     inputBox.Controls.Add(okButton);

     return inputBox.ShowDialog();
   }
   ```

Comment: As per my knowledge it will not display error message but when you put your cursor on error icon then it will display that error message as a toolTip.

Comment: That now makes perfect sense. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me explain about ErrorProvider.

1. ErrorProvider in Windows Application has following behaviour.

   - It will display error icon as per configuration.
   - It will display error message that you have set once you put your mouse cursor on it.
2. The behaviour you want is too display error message along with icon.

   - There is one solution build your own control just like ErrorProvider.